# Typescript namespaces and duplicate identifiers in concatenated js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, namespaces, typescript

I'm new to Typescript and am trying to get my head around namespaces and how to reference Interfaces which were defined in separate files.  I'm coming from a .NET C# background, so what I'm used to is to create each class & interface in their own file.

INationalRailService:

```
//// <reference path="../../../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../../typings/app.d.ts" />

namespace Interfaces {
    export interface INationalRailService {
        getDepartures(city: String): ng.IPromise<IQueryResult>;
        getArrivals(city: String): ng.IPromise<IQueryResult>;
    }
}
```

IJourney.ts

```
namespace Interfaces {
    export interface IJourney {
        locationName: string;
        crs: string;
        via: string;
        futureChangeTo: string;
        assocIsCancelled: boolean;
    }
}
```

In the tsd.d.ts I have references to the frameworks I'm using, namely Angular, JQuery, Typescript, toastr and angular-route.

In my app.d.ts file I have references to the .ts files I've created

```
// Interfaces
/// <reference path="../src/app/NationalRailViewerApp/Interfaces/ITrainServices.ts" />
/// <reference path="../src/app/NationalRailViewerApp/Interfaces/INationalRailService.ts" />
/// <reference path="../src/app/NationalRailViewerApp/Interfaces/IParameters.ts" />
/// <reference path="../src/app/NationalRailViewerApp/Interfaces/IJourney.ts" />
/// <reference path="../src/app/NationalRailViewerApp/Interfaces/IQueryResult.ts" />

// Implementations
/// <reference path="../src/app/NationalRailViewerApp/Implementations/QueryResult.ts" />
/// <reference path="../src/app/NationalRailViewerApp/Implementations/Journey.ts" />
/// <reference path="../src/app/NationalRailViewerApp/Implementations/NationalRailService.ts" />
/// <reference path="../src/app/NationalRailViewerApp/Implementations/TrainServices.ts" />
```

I can get the various classes, controllers and services to recognise the related interfaces by adding the reference path tags to the top of my files.

My problems arise when I attempt to transpile this to Javascript (ES5).  My gulp task runner uses gulp-typescript to output my javascript to a single .js file using the { out: 'output.js' } configuration option.

However I get a load of warnings about there being a 'Duplicate identifier "Interfaces" and subsequently, my resulting angular module will not load.

If I'm to make those interfaces available to my other files through a common namespace, why is this then causing me problems in the resulting Javascript?

Am I misusing the namespace keyword or misunderstanding how this is supposed to work?  Can I not use namespaces if I intend to concatenate my resulting javascript into a single file?

I've tried to fix this myself by reading the following article,

[Typescript Namespaces](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Namespaces.md)

but I just can't get my head around which I'm supposed to use for this example, namespaces or modules.

Comment: that example works fine for me, however I am not using the reference tag to configure the project, instead I have a tsconfig.json created with tsc --init.

Comment: So it looks like everything you are doing is correct, though I use msbuild to transpile my TypeScript, which makes it so I don't have to use the <reference> tags (since it automatically uses all the .ts file in the project). What is the actual runtime error you get that prevents your angular module from loading?

Comment: It was just the generic module load error.  Thankfully now though, with the inclusion of the tsconfig.js file (I think that's what fixed it) and some reworking to remove the /// references and fully qualifying the Interface names, I was able to get it to transpile and run successfully.

Comment: @toskv If you put your comment about using a tsconfig.json file as an Answer, I will mark it as such, since that is what ultimately helped me progress.

Comment: @GarethOates Thanks, but it looks like it took more than just that. It would be better (for the greater good) if you would make an answer with all that was needed to fix the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was with my Editor (VS Code).  When I closed and re-opened the editor following a gulp build of my project, the errors about duplicates went away.

Thanks for the responses anyway guys.